# How to put several children into the same place of parent component distinguishing by z?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, z-order

I want to make wizard dialog and put all it's pages in place, having current one on top and visible.

Also I want that `pack()` method resized dialog according to largemost page.

How to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

Card layout just doesn't work for me. In an example below the last color displayed is green, while it should be blue. Colors during work also unexpected.

What is wrong with example below?

```
 package tests.javax.swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Try_CardLayout {

    public static void addComponents(Container container) throws InterruptedException {

        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        container.setLayout(cardLayout);

        JPanel redPanel = new JPanel() {
            {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                setBackground(Color.red);
                add(new JLabel("Red panel"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        };

        JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel() {
            {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                setBackground(Color.green);
                add(new JLabel("Green panel"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        };

        JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel() {
            {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                setBackground(Color.blue);
                add(new JLabel("Blue panel"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        };

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        container.add(redPanel, "red");
        System.out.println("Red panel added");

        System.out.println(container.getComponentCount());

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        container.add(greenPanel, "green");
        System.out.println("Green panel added");
        System.out.println(container.getComponentCount());

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        container.add(bluePanel, "blue");
        System.out.println("Blue panel added");
        System.out.println(container.getComponentCount());

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        cardLayout.show(container, "red");
        System.out.println("Red panel selected");
        System.out.println(container.getComponentCount());

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        cardLayout.show(container, "green");
        System.out.println("Green panel selected");
        System.out.println(container.getComponentCount());

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        cardLayout.show(container, "blue");
        System.out.println("Blue panel selected");
        System.out.println(container.getComponentCount());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        addComponents(frame.getRootPane());

    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Is it possible to select visible component by reference in card layout, not by String id?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. There are method `first(), last(), next(), previous()` where you don't need to reference a string.

Comment: I want to select specific component to show. I have this component in variable like `JPanel mypanel = ...`. Now I want to show `mypanel`.

Comment: There's no method of `CardLayout` to do that. Is there a problem with using a String?

Comment: My be if I add the same component second time it just goes on top?

Comment: Sounds more like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html